# MySQL Duplicate entry for key unique key

Tags: mysql, index, unique-constraint

I have a table with a unique key which is a combination of 4 columns. Column A,B,C and D.

The values in the columns are like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111000 | 150100_XYZ_XY02 | 150100-A2_WXYZ_XY02 | 150100-A2_17090000_WXYZ_XY02B |
| 222111 | 150122_XYZ_XY02 | 150122-A2_WXYZ_XY02 | 150122-A2_17090000_WXYZ_XY02B |

When I insert the following record in the table,

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 222111 | 150122_XYZ_XY02 | 150122-A2_WXYZ_XY02 | 150122-A2_17090000_WXYZ_XY02 |

Notice that the only difference is last character of the `Column D`. It throws the exception:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry '222111-150122_XYZ_XY02-150122-A2_WXYZ_XY02-150122-A2_17090000_WXYZ_XY02' for key 'my_table_unique_idx1'
```

Even though there's a difference in the value of one column, why there would be an exception?

Update: Here's the schema:

```
 CREATE TABLE mytable
(
   my_uuid  VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
   s_id                               VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
   p_id                                VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
   pl_id                                  VARCHAR(100)    NOT NULL,
   ac_id                               VARCHAR(100),
   m_seg                              VARCHAR(100),
   et_date                            DATETIME,
   etr_date                  DATETIME,
   refreshed_date                           TIMESTAMP,
   created_date                             TIMESTAMP       DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   updated_date                             TIMESTAMP       DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   deleted_date                             TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`, `my_uuid`),
UNIQUE KEY `really_really_long_name_for_unique_idx1` (`p_id`,`s_id`,`pl_id`,`ac_id`),
  KEY `really_really_long_name_for_updated_date` (`updated_date`),
  KEY `really_really_long_name_for_seg_idx_1` (`m_seg`),
  KEY `really_really_long_name_for_et_date_idx_1` (`et_date`),
  KEY `really_really_long_name_for_etr_date_idx_1`(`etr_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (p_id)
PARTITIONS 100 */
```

Here's the fiddle - I am unable to reproduce the same in fiddle though: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=59ed46385738617c8b456f8b661a96fd

Comment: I would suggest posting the definition of my_table_unique_idx1. While you may think it is on columns A,B,C,D perhaps it is only on columns A,B,C?

Comment: I am preparing a fiddle and also adding the definition here in a few minutes

Comment: @ErgestBasha I have updated the description with fiddle

Comment: @NickSI have added the definition

Comment: @JohnEisbrener No, I am not -

Comment: Comments [and discussion moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137436/discussion-between-ypercube-and-vishal-kotecha).

Answer (score 1):

UNIQUE indexes do not work with PARTITIONed tables.

Furthermore, having the partition key be the *first* column in an index is almost always not useful.

Comment: thank you for looking into this, could you please what should be the approach then? Also, could you share the documentation link supporting your answer, if that's okay? Thanks again!

Comment: @Vishal_Kotecha - Much experimentation, summarized in blog on [_Partitioning_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).  So far, I see no benefit in Partitioning; what other queries do you have?  The lack of UNIQUE and FK is mentioned in the main docs, plus in multiple feature requests (aka bug reports).

Comment: Wow, that's a killer - good to know!